# designer.cs weirdness

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, designer

I recently checked out a large C# code base that I will be doing some work with, and converted the project(s) from VS2005 to VS2008. On building the solution, I seem to have generated a bunch of designer.cs files that do not belong there. I am now getting class re-declared errors. Note the designer.cs (and the associated resx files) have been generatated from classes that are just plain old C# classes, that should not have a designer attached at all.

I can delete these files and that fixes the problem, the issue is I have 500+ of these (from a code base of approx 14000 files) so this is going to be a painful process to work out the false ones and delete. More importantly I want to know why / how this happened.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does there seem to be any pattern to the files that have designer files attached? Do they use resources, UI files, are they just bog standard code files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up the .csproj file in a text editor - it's just XML and the format is relatively simple. Files that should have designers have an additional entry:

```
<Compile Include="MyForm.cs">
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="MyForm.Designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>MyForm.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

If there's nothing readily apparent create a new VS2008 project and add some dummy classes of the same types as the ones you're having issues with. You can look at that new project's .csproj file as a reference for how your files should appear.

Comment: Thx, this would have been useful last month, this is pretty much what I ended up doing. I ended up writing a small app to generate a new proj file and (touch wood) it's been fine ever since. I still have no idea why it did what it did, which I admit gnaws away at me.